# Confusing IllegalStateException: Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines, onactivityresult

I have looked at the other questions/answers and they don't seem to apply here.

As you can see I am declaring and registering the ActivityResultLauncher as a top level property.

Yet I am still experiencing the IllegalStateException in production which I am unable to reproduce, so the confusion is how can this be? Wouldn't it always register before it is accessed?

I suspect maybe it the fact that the launch call is in a coroutine but I'm just guessing. The error does seem to be happening when the activity is resumed after being killed of by Android from what I can tell from the logs.

```
class MainActivity {

    private val startAnotherActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
        //Does stuff with the result
    }

    override fun onResume(){
        if(someConditionTrue) launchAnotherActivity()
    }

    fun launchAnotherActivity(){
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val user = viewModel.someSuspendDBCall()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, TheOtherActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(USERID, user.id)
            startAnotherActivityResult.launch(intent) //<--- The error happens here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the same exception is also thrown if the activity has already been destroyed by the time you call `startAnotherActivityResult.launch` (as it is automatically unregistered on destroy). Is your coroutine cancelled (e.g., does `isActive` return false)? Maybe your `someSuspendDBCall` isn't as suspending as you think

Comment: @ianhanniballake That is interesting, I guess I figure the lifecycleScope would protect me against the coroutine running once the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Did you found the issue.? I have the same problem with in app update